# How to set the content of a g:textArea as HTML (formatted text, not code) in grails

Tags: html, grails, formatting, textarea, gsp

I have a small grails app which I am in the middle of writing.

In one action, the show, the 'show.gsp' page is called, in which is a text area:

As shown in 'value', the value is to be some formatted text (i.e., HTML) such as:

```
<p>Writing some html </p>
<p>we can <strong>bold</strong> it</p>
<p>and <em>italic</em> it</p>
<p>and send it!</p>
<p>sean</p>
<p> </p>
```

### However, instead of showing up as:

Writing some html

we can **bold** it

and *italic* it

and send it!

sean

---

the HTML is shown as code (I assume the html is being escaped, even though i've set the attribute escapeHtml="false".

Or, do I have it wrong? How else can I insert the HTML into a textArea as formatted text?

Thanks!

sean

Comment: Textareas don't display html, they display text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With textarea you can't. Try to use WYSIWYG editors like [CKEditor](http://grails.org/plugin/ckeditor)